# Sentry custom 500 handler

Tags: django, sentry

I have a custom 500 hander to use with sentry. In my urls.py file i have:

```
def handler500(request):
    """
    500 error handler which includes ``request`` in the context.

    Templates: `500.html`
    Context: None
    """
    from django.template import Context, loader
    from django.http import HttpResponseServerError

    t = loader.get_template('500.html') # You need to create a 500.html template.
    return HttpResponseServerError(t.render(RequestContext(request)))
```

And in my 500.html template:

```
{% extends "intranet/index.html" %}

{% block main_content %}
<h1>Internal Error!</h1>
<p>You've encountered an error, please try again in some time or file an 
error report if the problem persists. 
{% if request.sentry.id %}
You may reference this error as <strong>{{ request.sentry.id }}</strong>.
{% endif %}
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

This works on my local machine, but not on my webhost.
The apache logs contain this error:

```
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     args = md5_constructor(u':'.join([urlquote(resolve_variable(var, context)) for var in self.vary_on])), referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/mypath/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 630, in resolve_variable, referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return Variable(path).resolve(context), referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/mypath/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 696, in resolve, referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     value = self._resolve_lookup(context), referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/mypath/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 749, in _resolve_lookup, referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r", (bit, current)) # missing attribute, referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
[Thu Mar 31 22:09:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [request] in u'[{}, {\\'block\\': <Block Node: body. Contents: [<Text Node: \\'\\n<body>\\n<div id="page">\\n\\'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \\'\\n<div id="container" clas\\'>, <Block Node: container. Contents: [<Text Node: \\'\\n\\'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \\'\\n<div id="main_content" c\\'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \\'">\\n<div id="breadcrumbs">\\'>, <Block Node: main_content. Contents: [<Text Node: \\'\\n\\n<div id="actions">\\n\\'>, <Block Node: actions. Contents: [<Text Node: \\'\\n\\'>]>, <Text Node: \\'\\n</div>\\n<div id="content"\\'>, <Block Node: content. Contents: [<Text Node: \\'\\n\\'>]>, <Text Node: \\'\\n</div>\\n</div>\\n\\'>]>, <Text Node: \\'\\n<div style="clear: both;\\'>]>, <Text Node: \\'\\n</div>\\n\\'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \\'\\n<div style="clear: both;\\'>]>}, {\\'block\\': <Block Node: notifications. Contents: [<Text Node: \\'\\n    \\'>, <django.templatetags.cache.CacheNode object at 0xb3faa8c>, <Text Node: \\'\\n    \\'>]>}]', referer: https://myurl.com/view/b4bddfa9da6d40fb8bad3e68393a8efb
```

This is driving me crazy. Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your settings absolutely 100% the same between dev and production?

Make sure you have `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

While i don't see anything in your template that should complain this loudly, you must have something in another template causing this problem.

Hope that's the case!

http://groups.google.com/group/django-feincms/browse_thread/thread/8beccc194a6d6cf7/d843a074f300c9e9?#d843a074f300c9e9

http://daniel.hepper.net/blog/2010/11/how-to-fix-variabledoesnotexist-exception-in-django/

Comment: There are a few different settings, but thats just things like debug etc, and they are in a different local_settings file that i import.

Comment: Also, I have "django.core.context_processors.request" in my settings. Any ideas? Im at the edge, il be ripping out my hair any minute :D

Comment: Yup, only on the 500 page :'(

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita "While i don't see anything in your template that should complain this loudly" -- the template tries to access an attribute of the request: `request.sentry.id`

Comment: @zsquare `django.core.context_processors` has moved in django 1.10 so you now need `django.template.context_processors.request`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error appear for two additional (in addition to the missing part in the `TEPMLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`) reasons:

- models were out of date - run syncdb and migrate and this went away
- urlconf was not defined in the urls.py - all urlconfs were neatly commented  out.